# unity how to changing panel color when click button

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, colors, panel

i want to Change panel color when i click button  , i try with 
code its change button color not panel color

```
public Image panel;
  // Use this for initialization
  void Start () {
      panel = GetComponent<Image>();
  }

  // Update is called once per frame
 public void OnButtonClick {


      panel.color = GetRandomColor();

  }
  Color GetRandomColor(){

      return new Color(Random.value, Random.value, Random.value);
  }

}
```

What do I need to do?

Comment: There is no button interaction in your code at all

Comment: However your code does change the color of the panel every frame.

Comment: I guess what you need to do is to watch some tutorials. But in this case just change `void Update` to `public void OnButtonClick` and assign this method for OnClick event of your button

Comment: i test to change void Update to public void OnButtonClick and assign this method for OnClick event its change the button color not panel help please

Comment: No offence, but it seems that you have no idea what you are doing. I highly doubt that you are working on some real project, so I guess you are learning. So better try to read some docs and watch tutorials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, what the heck, I will explain why it's not working and what you should do.

(I assume you changed Update method as I suggested in comments)

First of all you should check to what GameObject your script is attached in the Editor. I assume it is attached to the Button. So what is happening in the Start method? Right — you are assigning `Image` component of the Button to `panel` variable. So when `panel.color = GetRandomColor();` is called it changes color of the `Image` component of the Button.

What can you do about this? Simple way would be to remove `Start` method completely and since `panel` variable is declared as `public` assign it to panel GameObject in the Editor.

Comment: obywan thanks for your help so useful  i assign `gameobject` not `panel` thanks for your reminder but answer is to remove start also thanks so thanks

Answer (score 0):

You don't have any button, and you've made it so the panel's color would change every frame, not every click.
You have to create a button, enter it as a parameter to the code, and use the OnClick event.
More about this here: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.Button-onClick.html